# How to package Angular 2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, build

I've made a mistake of using [Angular QuickStart Source](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md) provided by Google to create my application. I've overlooked the line in their description saying that: 'It is not the perfect arrangement for the application and it is not designed for production.'

Anyhow, I still need to package it into a single .js file along with all dependencies (preferably everything minified).

I can't figure out how to do so. Any ideas? Porting it to [Angular 2 Starter kit](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) or something like Google's [Angular Cli](https://cli.angular.io/), would be too much of a hassle at this point I think (different structure, etc.)...so for this one I just want to stick to Angular QuickStart Source.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Angular documentation explain how to pre-compile your application (component, service, ...) and how to bundle it with RollupJS.

See [Ahead-of-time compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)

Comment: I've tried to follow the guide step by step, but it doesn't work... ngc -p keeps failing on resource file not found (for index.html). I can't believe there isn't a simple way to do this... Ability to build the app is the most important part of developing an application.

Comment: You have to follow really strict convention to allow AoT compilation. Problems come when you use third party libs that does not follow this conventions. Did you try to compile really basic application with a single component ?

Comment: I got around the problem with index.html, but now it complains about one of the import statements for moment.js... it's a real pain...

Comment: Is it ngc or rollup that compain about the import ?

Comment: My application works just fine, yet this AOT compiler is giving me literally hundred different errors... Anything better to try?

Comment: I can't say. I just spend the week refactoring our main site code and our multiple internal libs to make it compatible with AoT. Now it works just fine with a single bundle.js file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124079/discussion-between-noemi-salaun-and-jjj).

Comment: ah dear, looks like I will just extract .js file manually and copy them over as they are along with all references to node_modules js files... it's not going to be optimized, it'll be large, etc... but I've spent half a day on something that should be as easy as running a command...

Answer (score 0):

Webpack suits your needs. There is an awesome tutorial in [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)